# Javascript variables and debugging (trying to use JQVMap)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to gain more working familiarity with jquery/js.

I am playing around with jqvmap.com mapping code.

I would like to create a map that has one of 4 colors depending on the state.  My initial attempts at doing this failed.

I have the original coding working fine.  See [here](http://pollster.net/index2.html).

But when I try to write in specific coding for each state, I am making some fundamental mistake.  See [here](http://pollster.net/index.html).

I am hoping that someone can lead me in the right direction on this specific code.

I am also hoping to get some guidance on how to debug JS code.  Right now, I see that my changes are not working, and I have no idea how to debug anything.

Comment: first thing when working with js is use a browser console to look at erorrs. When page loads, can isntatntly see this line being a problem:  `if (name == 'CA' or name='VA' or name='TX')`. You can't put an `if` as property of an object . F12 on most modern browsers for console. Focus on how to use the callbacks of the plugin

Comment: I changed things around a bit, hoping that I can do the following: `jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', {us: '#FF0000'});`  Any tips?   This is used [here](http://pollster.net/index.html)